# How do I get BUTTONS to toggle through an array using next() and prev()?

Tags: php, html

How do I put a button in my page to toggle through an array using next() and prev()?

```
$transportation = array('foot', 'bike', 'car', 'plane');
```

---

```
<button onclick="$mode = next($transportion);">NEXT</button>
<p>
<button onclick="$mode = prev($transportion);">PREVIOUS</button>
<p>
```

---

```
echo $mode;
```

Comment: side tip: generally best to use Event Listeners over inline onClick. Seperation of code is best way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP File Code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php $transportation = array('foot', 'bike', 'car', 'plane'); ?>
        <h2>Foot, Bike, Car, Plane</h2>
        <p>
            <input type="button" class="cycle" id="next" value="Next">
        </p>
            <h2 id="result">Current: plane</h2>
        <p>
            <input type="button" class="cycle" id="prev" value="Previous">
        </p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myarray = <?php echo json_encode($transportation); ?>;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var current = -1;
                $(".cycle").click(function () {
                    var darray = myarray;
                    if ($(this).attr("id") == "next") {
                        next(darray);
                } else {
                    prev(darray);
                }
            });

            function next(data) {
                if (current != 3) {
                    $("#result").text("Current: " + data[++current]);
                }
            }

            function prev(data) {
                if (current != 0) {
                    $("#result").text("Current: " + data[--current]);
                }
            }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Live Example:**

> `http://69.195.223.90/56454-11/`

Answer (score 1):

[check this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593802/php-arrays-next-and-prev?rq=1)

As just mentioned, PHP is a server-side language so you will need to deal with it from the PHP side. Assuming that you work on a MVC environment you have the controller handle the 
"prev" and "next" requests and render it to the view.

If you, for example, render the array in a table or list, you could use JQuery, for instance, but then it will be on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this straight away. PHP is a server-side language. You will need client-side scripting to send a command to the server. Or you could use a javascript array.