# Previous/Next buttons for PHP array chunks

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, xml, chunks

I'm trying to create some next/previous buttons for a form that uses an external XML array. I've split the array into chunks with the plan to navigate between each chunk with the next/previous buttons. I've managed to get it working (sort of) whereby I have corresponding next and previous buttons for each chunk, but I obviously only need one of each button on screen. I fear I may have gone about it the wrong way... Is this perhaps a better job for javascript than php?

Also had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593802/php-arrays-next-and-prev) stack question but I can't get any of those solutions working with the array chunks... Any insight is much appreciated.

Many thanks

```
     <?php
       $xml=simplexml_load_file("../scSHARE/editor.xml");
       $xml_array = (array) $xml;
       $chunks=array_chunk($xml_array["Slot"], 4);
       $i=1;

       foreach($chunks as $bank){ 
     ?>
     <div id="bank_menu" class="menu-item menu-item-<?php echo $i;?>" data-target=".bank_<?php echo $i; ?>">
       <a href="">Next</a>
       <a href="">Prev</a>
     </div>
     <?php $i++;}?>
```

Comment: You need to pass an offset, chunk number, or page number somehow (typically a URL parameter like `?offset=10`), and then you'd need to use that info. Right now, you're not doing any of the above.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132397/prev-next-buttons-for-a-circular-list) topic as well. May be it will be in help.

Comment: Ok, thanks, way over my head though. So Ed you're saying to get rid of the foreach loop and php echos and pass a chunk number in the url where the php echos are, so as to get the current chunk displayed +1/-1 or something? Sorry if thats not at all what you mean I'm still learning and can't quite get my head around what you're saying.

Time to read some more about arrays I think